# Ayuda metodo transcripción de ADN a ARN?

Tags: c++

Se desea convertir una secuencia de ADN en una secuencia de ARN. Para ello, declare una clase ADN con un atributo secuencia y un método Transcripcion. Además, implemente otros métodos que considere necesarios para resolver el problema. Finalmente, valide que la secuencia de ADN dada sea correcta.
Ejemplo de entrada/salida del programa Entre la secuencia de ADN: AGCTACGTAGCT La secuencia de ADN es correcta Longitud de secuencia= 12 La secuencia de ARN es: UCGAUGCAUCGA

Esto es lo que hemos hecho pero de ahi para allá estamos trancado:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma hdrstop

class ADN {
   private:
      string secuencia;
   public:
      ADN(string _secuencia);
      string GetSecuencia();
      int Longitud();
      string Transcripcion();
      string GetTranscripcion();

};
  ADN::ADN(string _secuencia){
     secuencia=_secuencia;
  }
  string ADN::GetSecuencia(){
     return secuencia;
  }

  int ADN::Longitud(){
   return secuencia.length();
  }

  string ADN::Transcripcion(){
    for (int i=0;i=secuencia.length();i++)
    if (secuencia[i]=='T') {
        secuencia[i]=='U';
}
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main( char Secuencia_ADN)
 {
 cout<<"Inserte secuencia de ADN";
  cin>>Secuencia_ADN;
  ADN a1("Secuencia_ADN");
 cout<<"La secuencia de ADN es:"<< a1.GetSecuencia()<< endl;
 cout<<"La longitud de la secuencia es:"<<a1.Longitud()<<endl;
 cout<<"La secuencia de ARN es: "<<a1.GetSecuencia()<<endl;



 system("pause");
        return 0;

}
```

El error esta enque cuando lo ejecuto no me lee la secuencia introducida sino lee Secuencia_ADN y me dice que la longitud es 13, o sea no se corresponde.Me debe transcribir o sea entro la secuencia y la salida debe ser igual solo cambiando la T por la U.

Comment: El problema esta en el main..que cuando lo corro y me pide la secuencia, entro una, pero lo que me pone es: La secuencia es Secuencia_ADN y la longitud es 13, o sea no se cumple para la cadena que yo entro

Comment: done!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `main` tienes varias cosas fuera de lugar:

```
ADN a1("Secuencia_ADN");
```

Le dice:

> Crea una instancia de la clase `ADN` e inicializa el valor de la cadena interna (`secuencia`) a la literal (Constante) `"Secuencia_ADN"`.

Si te fijas, la longitud de la cadena "Secuencia_ADN" es 13, por ende siempre te va a dar ese resultado.

Y:

```
int main(char Secuencia_ADN) {
  ...
}
```

No debería ni dejarte compilar (En teoría).

Entonces, ¿Qué debes hacer para arreglar los errores? Es facil, empecemos desde arriba:

Cambia *(Como buena práctica)*:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Por:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std; // no recomendado.
```

Luego, en tu método `main`:

```
int main() {
  string Secuencia_ADN = "";               // Aqui cambia la cosa!!!
  cout << "Inserte secuencia de ADN: ";
  cin >> Secuencia_ADN;

  ADN a1(Secuencia_ADN);                   // Quitamos las comillas.
  cout << "La secuencia de ADN es:" << a1.GetSecuencia() << endl;
  cout << "La longitud de la secuencia es:" << a1.Longitud() << endl;
  cout << "La secuencia de ARN es: " << a1.GetSecuencia() << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Para finalizar, arreglemos esa función para generar las secuencias:

```
string ADN::Transcripcion(){
  string 
  for (int i=0;i=secuencia.length();i++)
    if (secuencia[i]=='T') {
      secuencia[i]=='U';
  }
}
```

`i = secuencia.length()` <- esta no es una condición como tal, debido a que siempre será verdadera porque asigna `secuencia.length()` a la variable `i` y se queda en loop al llamarse.

Solución (Mis practicas de C++ no son las mejores, pero puedes obtener una idea con ellas :P):

```
string ADN::Transcripcion() {
  string out = ""; // Realmente no se si esta bien :p
  for (int i = 0; i <= secuencia.length(); i++)
    out += (secuencia[i] == 'T')? 'U': secuencia[i];
  return out;
}
```

Y si aún así quieres que se pierda la cadena original, cambia el método de arriba por:

```
string ADN::Transcripcion() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= secuencia.length(); i++)
    secuencia[i] = (secuencia[i] == 'T')? 'U': secuencia[i];
  return secuencia;
}
```

Con eso debería bastar.

El código completo: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SurprisedSnivelingIdentifier) y un [ideone](https://ideone.com/n194hC), saludos :)

Comment: Casi, compila ok, pero con el único defecto que no me cambia la T por la U. Cómo soluciono eso????string ADN::Transcripcion() {
  string out = ""; // Realmente no se si esta bien :p
  for (int i = 0; i <= secuencia.length(); i++)
    out += (secuencia[i] == 'T')? 'U': secuencia[i];
  return out;
}

Comment: Si vi el link lo descagué y lo ejecuté pero sigue sin cambiarme la T por la U

Comment: En el main se pide insertar la cadena , me dice la longitud, pero no veo como hace la transcripcion

Comment: cORRECTO ESTABA INSERTANDO algo mas

Comment: Ahora me surge una duda como hago para controlar que el usuario solo pueda insertar los caracteres G T A C, solo esos, pues la T se cambia por la U...solo existen esas bases. no puede introducir ningun otro caracter!!!!

Comment: Deberías realizar otra pregunta al respecto, la duda que tenías sobre esta ya se resolvió, es lo más recomendado.

Comment: Y como me aconsejas formule la otra pregunta?????

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask @AsielCabreraGuerrero aqui tienes como formular una pregunta